# Display a menu and select from SQl some details?

Tags: php, mysql

From the begin i have the following code.

http://www.imagebam.com/image/15786f368414506

I try to post the code and insert an image but i can't

Basicaly i have a website for phone repairs.And i want to create in iphone.php a menu from DB and when i acces the menu with _GET variable, when i press Iphone 5s (iphone.php?id=id page) the code have to display to me,all reparations for iphone 5s.

Until now,i succsed to create the Menu but the keep add same line in the menu when i add for example a second reparation for 5s.And i don't know how to select all reparation for 5s and display them in a single link like above  Iphone 5s (iphone.php?id=id page).

Now the script working like this.Create a menu with all phone names.

Iphone 5s
Iphone 3
Iphone 3s
Iphone 4
Iphone 5s
Iphone 5s

Shoud be like

Iphone 5s
Iphone 3
Iphone 3s
Iphone 4
Other new devices..

And display the reparation in every link from list By ID.i try it to select by phone names,not working.

Any body with any ideea please?

Thx so much

Comment: Please copy your code here, we can not help you without the code.

Comment: i can't copy the code,apper some error with 4 spaces..i don't know how to fix it.But anyway i solve my problem.I had to put DISTING after select,and make the selection after phonemodel. thx anyway.